# How can I make a subview show up on top of the keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am adding a view that fades in that gives my user alerts like successful login etc. Unfortunately the view does not appear above the keyboard so half of it gets hidden because I am displaying it in the center.

```
case 401:
                alertBezel = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
                [self.view addSubview:alertBezel];

                // Make the customViews 37 by 37 pixels for best results (those are the bounds of the build-in progress indicators)
                alertBezel.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]] autorelease];
                alertBezel.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
                alertBezel.labelText = @"Unauthorized User!";
                [alertBezel show:YES];
                [alertBezel hide:YES afterDelay:1];
                break;
```

I also tried getting the key window:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]
```

No luck.

Comment: So your view gets hidden by the keyboard. Is that your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should really be using a UIAlertView.  That will show up over the keyboard.

Below are some resources on customizing alert views:

[how i can implement a custom UIAlertview with a progress bar and a cancel button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656309/how-i-can-implement-a-custom-uialertview-with-a-progress-bar-and-a-cancel-button)

http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/08/14/custom-uialertview-color-chooser/

Answer (score 0):

You could animate it up, by modifying its property when the keyboard shows up, or when your user go to the next field.