# UIAlertView with a progressbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

I would like to have an UIAlertView showing when I'm uploading my file to the server. But because the files can be huge (up to 500MB) it really needs to have a progress bar. Right now i have a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to show the app is buisy, but this is not very user friendly in my opinion.

I can't get this to work at all, I would be most gratefull for any help in this matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the answer on [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656309/how-i-can-implement-a-custom-uialertview-with-a-progress-bar-and-a-cancel-button) gives the best advise. In short, rethink the UI.

Comment: That is actually a very good point.. However, when the app is uploading there is nothing you can really do at that time..

Comment: In that case you could create a UIView with the progress bar and anything else you might need and then put that view at the top layer. This should intercept any touch events. When the download finished you can them remove the UIView which will restore the regular state of your app. This way you get the same benefits of the alert view but will take much less time to implement.

Comment: I have intergrated the progress bar on the main page. The buttons that could harm the upload are disabled until the upload is finished. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

A while back I found that I needed a UITextField embedded in an UIAlterView, and came across some pretty useful code here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html

Around the 5th or 6th post there's a tutorial on how to add a TextField. Adding a UIProgressView should be a very similar task.

I should mention though, the app I used the code in was not submitted to the app store. I can't comment on whether or not the code complies with Apple's policies, but maybe another user here can comment on that?